# How to use value of useState using react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

```
const SettingsContainer = () => {
    const [settingsData, setSettingsData] = useState({})

    const { show_abe = false, show_def = false } = settingsData;

    const refreshSettings = () => {
        getSettings().then((resp) => {
            setSettingsData(resp.data);
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        refreshSettings();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {show_abe ? 
                <abc></abc> : null
            }
            {show_def ? 
                <def></def> : null
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default SettingsContainer;
```

tried below test case

```
    const respData = { show_abe = true, show_def = true };

    jest.mock('../../hooks/apis', () => ({
        getSettings: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: { respData } })),
        
    }));

    describe('SettingsContainer', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            render(<HashRouter><SettingsContainer /></HashRouter>);
        });

        test('Should Display Page Heading', () => {
            expect(screen.getByText('Settings')).toBeInTheDocument();
        });

        test('Check if child component has been loaded or not', async () => {
            await waitFor(() => {
                expect(screen.getByTestId('abc')).toHaveTextContent('ABC');
                expect(screen.getByTestId('def')).toHaveTextContent('DEF');
        })});
    });
```

How to write a test case to show `abc` component and `def` which I receive from API call and I set that data in state using `useState`, using React Testing Library?

Comment: I suppose you'd mock the `getSettings` function, whatever that is, to return the data you expect the `settingsData` state to be updated to that will make the rendering conditions you want to test true. What have you tried already in your testing? Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: Looks like `respData` is missing `show_abe` and `show_def` properties for the `SettingsContainer` to toggle true and conditionally render on. Perhaps `show_abe` and `show_def` were just placeholders in your initial edit. Can you explain/clarify what the issue is specifically in the test(s)?

Comment: @DrewReese I am not able get the values show_abe = true, show_def = true post API success, in the original code, I am setting the API response in settingsData which is derived from useSate..
Now how to access settingsData in test case to render the component